# Server does not support secure connections using company address

Tags: c#, vb.net

```vb
Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("admin@website.com.my", "password")
Smtp_Server.Port = 587
Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
Smtp_Server.Host = "mail2.website.com.my"
'smtp-mail.outlook.com
e_mail = New MailMessage()
e_mail.From = New MailAddress(txtfeedbackname.Text)
e_mail.To.Add(txtfeedbackname.Text)
e_mail.Subject = "eConnect - Feedback from Employee"
e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
e_mail.Body = txtComment.Text
Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
```

It working fine in gmail for smtp server host. When i change it to my own smtp it showing error:

> Error: Server does not support secure connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to install SSL on your server, or disable SSL on the connection string.

Right now you try to connect with:

```
Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = true
```

Set this to false and you should be able to connect.

Comment: I was going to say... you had XML there before :')